# How to construct Hamiltonian for combinatorial optimization problems and then convert into Pauli basis?

Tags: vqe, qaoa, quantum-computing-for-finance

Suppose I have a portfolio optimization problem where I have to minimize,
$$qx^T\sum x - \mu^Tx$$

where q is the maximum risk and x is {0,1}^n and $\mu$ are the expected returns.

Now I have to convert this problem into Hamiltonian and subsequently find the Pauli Basis for it. How can I do so?

Comment: Are you going off a specific paper?

Comment: No not any paper

Comment: Ah, okay. Maybe look into general optimization problems? I'm not as familiar with creating Hamiltonians from general problems